# Cakephp 2.x relative path is not working but absulate path is working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, ubuntu

I have newly install Ubuntu server with Apache/2.4.7 ,Php  5.5.9 , mysql and uploaded my Cakephp project over there , My cakephp version is 2.4 but i am facing an issue, Its is not finding any css, images, or any other files which is define on webroot folder.

### example

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/css/style.css (Not working , giving 404 error)
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/js/min.jquery.js (Not working , giving 404 error)

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/app/webroot/css/style.css (working)
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/app/webroot/js/min.jquery.js (working)

### option which i have already checked.

- htaccess is working
- mod_rewrite is loading
- SERVER API is Apache not CGI or FASTCGI
- short Tag is open

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check AllowOverride value at apache2.conf file. By default is none. In order to work set it to "all"

Answer (score 0):

Check that your virtual host is configured correctly. You should have `AllowOverride All` in your vhost's conf file, something like this:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.com">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```